# How to make soapui project path relative to the testrunner batchfile path?

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I've been using readyapi! SoapUI for API testing. I'm using the `testrunner` batchfile for commandline execution.

However, my Project Path is static, ex. **-fC:\example-soapui-project.html**.

How do I make the path relative to the batch file?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: soapui projects are owned by customers or end users and they will be in a different location and absolute path is passed to test runner. What is problem with this approach? or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Currently, we commit our projects on `tfs`. For the `testrunner` to work, We and our clients should have the same folder path for the project passed to the `testrunner`. Our goal is to make the `testrunner` work on different paths. Thank you

Comment: Not sure how does it matter. Of course, most of the users uses some kind of repository for their projects. By the way, each one will checkout in different location. Why not use an environment variable to the checkout location?

Comment: We've been searching this day and finally we found a solution. We've used `%~dp0`. Thank you very much for your time and interest in answering!